# How to optimise query containing subqueries from same table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am very new to ms sql so pardon

I have a table which contains all comments from client as well as admin. I have to select unique conversession with time the query was placed and time when it was first confirmed.

The query is:

```
  SELECT CONVERT(DATE, [t0].[CommDate]) AS [CommDate2], [t0].[TicketId], [t0].[TransactionID], (
SELECT MIN([t1].[CommDate])
FROM [dbo].[CommentsHistory] AS [t1]
WHERE ([t1].[TicketId] = [t0].[TicketId]) AND ([t1].[CommentFrom] LIKE '%Client%')
) AS [AskedMinDate], (
SELECT MIN([t2].[CommDate])
FROM [dbo].[CommentsHistory] AS [t2]
WHERE ([t2].[TicketId] = [t0].[TicketId]) AND (NOT ([t2].[CommentFrom] LIKE '%Client%'))
) AS [ResponseMinDate] FROM [dbo].[CommentsHistory] AS [t0]
 WHERE (CONVERT(DATE, [t0].[CommDate]) >= DATEADD(mm,-1,GETDATE())) AND ([t0].[TicketId] IS NOT NULL)
ORDER BY [t0].[TicketId] DESC, [t0].[CommDate]
```

I have applied index, but since columns contents are non- unique it is not of much help.

Are there any other way for writing these type of queries, or should i consider refactoring the table itself?

The above query gives the result but is too slow, I want to know that my query is not optimise or my choice of table creation is wrong?

[image]

Table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[CommentsHistory](
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [CommDate] [datetime] NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_CommentsHistory_CommDate]  DEFAULT (getdate()),
    [CommentFrom] [varchar](255) NULL,
    [Comments] [varchar](max) NULL,
    [TransactionID] [float] NULL,
    [splitnumber] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [MfrId] [int] NULL,
    [ShowClient] [bit] NULL,
    [ShowWareHouse] [bit] NULL,
    [IsResponse] [bit] NULL,
    [CustEmail] [varchar](150) NULL,
    [TicketId] [numeric](18, 0) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
```

Comment: Please tell us what you want to do. I cannot look at your code and imagine what you want.

Comment: Query is taking long time to complete

Comment: I see a lot of self joins. Why are you doing that ? BTW, you mind showing a screenshot of the output you expect ?

Comment: I have uploaded image.

Comment: The `CommentFrom LIKE '%Client%'`is properly what's killing your performance.
You properly need to rework your logic and either use Common Table Expression and Window functions to limit the data you select instead of subqueries or use some pre-calculated values.

Comment: Ratna, I have to ask you this again. What is your original table like and what is your goal (Eg.I want all comments in last month which received no replies). Then, maybe, we could modify your existing query or even give you a different query to achieve that goal.

Comment: Borat Sagdiyev I have updated the table creation defination, i need to select distinct ticket with min date replied by customer and admin

Comment: A little test data would be nice, because I suspect you can eleminate at least one of your sub queries using `MIN() OVER ()` - and potentially both, depending on how data appears.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't provide any data to test against, but my intuition is that running the sub-queries as `WITH` clauses will run faster because they'll run once and get joined in as opposed to running for every row in the main result set.

```
  WITH CLIENTCOMMENTDATE
    AS (SELECT [t1].[TicketId], MIN([t1].[CommDate]) AS [CommDate]
          FROM [dbo].[CommentsHistory] AS [t1]
         WHERE ([t1].[CommentFrom] LIKE '%Client%')
         GROUP BY [t1].[TicketId]
       )
     , RESPONSEDATE
    AS (SELECT [t2].[TicketId], MIN([t2].[CommDate]) AS [CommDate]
          FROM [dbo].[CommentsHistory] AS [t2]
         WHERE (NOT ([t2].[CommentFrom] LIKE '%Client%'))
         GROUP BY [t2].[TicketId]
       )
SELECT CONVERT(DATE, [t0].[CommDate]) AS [CommDate2], 
       [t0].[TicketId], [t0].[TransactionID], 
       [t1].[CommDate] AS [AskedMinDate],
       [t2].[CommDate] AS [ResponseMinDate]
  FROM [dbo].[CommentsHistory] AS [t0]
  LEFT JOIN CLIENTCOMMENTDATE [t1] ON [t1].[TicketId] = [t0].[TicketId]
  LEFT JOIN RESPONSEDATE [t2] ON [t2].[TicketId] = [t0].[TicketId]
 WHERE (CONVERT(DATE, [t0].[CommDate]) >= DATEADD(mm,-1,GETDATE())) 
   AND ([t0].[TicketId] IS NOT NULL)
 ORDER BY [t0].[TicketId] DESC, [t0].[CommDate]
;
```

Another thing that would speed it up is if instead of the `LIKE` operator you could use the equality operator, *e.g.* `[CommentFrom] = 'Client'`. That depends on whether or not the contents of the `CommentFrom` column are always exactly `'Client'` when the comment is from a client. If it is, then you can use the equality operator. If not, perhaps the column always *begins* with `'Client'` or it's always in the same position in the value so you could use [`LEFT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177601%28v=sql.100%29.aspx) or [`SUBSTRING`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187748%28v=sql.100%29.aspx), *e.g.* `LEFT([CommentFrom], 6) = 'Client'`.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use OUTER APPLY as shown below.

You may need to do some modifications in this Query

```
SELECT CONVERT(DATE, [t0].[CommDate]) AS [CommDate2], 
        [t0].[TicketId], [t0].[TransactionID],
        A.AskedMinDate,
        B.ResponseMinDate 
FROM [dbo].[CommentsHistory] AS [t0]
OUTER APPLY (
            SELECT MIN([t1].[CommDate]) AS AskedMinDate
            FROM [dbo].[CommentsHistory] AS [t1]
            WHERE ([t1].[TicketId] = [t0].[TicketId]) AND ([t1].[CommentFrom] LIKE '%Client%')
) AS A
OUTER APPLY (
            SELECT MIN([t2].[CommDate]) AS ResponseMinDate
            FROM [dbo].[CommentsHistory] AS [t2]
            WHERE ([t2].[TicketId] = [t0].[TicketId]) AND (NOT ([t2].[CommentFrom] LIKE '%Client%'))
) AS B
WHERE (CONVERT(DATE, [t0].[CommDate]) >= DATEADD(mm,-1,GETDATE())) AND ([t0].[TicketId] IS NOT NULL)
ORDER BY [t0].[TicketId] DESC, [t0].[CommDate]
```